# Simpler or faster methods to calculate a sum

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I would like to calculate $$s=\sum_0^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{\Gamma(1/2+k/2)}{\Gamma(1+k/2)}.$$
To do so I did the following 
\begin{align}
s&=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1/2)}\sum_0^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{\Gamma(1/2+k/2)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(1/2+1/2+k/2)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1/2)}\sum_0^{\infty}(-1)^kB(\frac12+\frac k2,\frac12)\\
&=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1/2)}\sum_0^{\infty}(-1)^k2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}[\sin(x)]^{2\times(\frac12+\frac k2)-1}[\cos(x)]^{2\times\frac12-1}dx\\
&=\frac{2}{\Gamma(1/2)}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sum_0^{\infty}(-1)^k[\sin(x)]^{k}dx\\
&=\frac{2}{\Gamma(1/2)}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{1+\sin x}dx\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\\
\end{align}

It took me some time to think of this solution, to me it hence is not the most straightforward way to follow. I was hence wondering if there is some other way which I could learn from it.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to insert a power of $z^k$ in each term, then split the sum into the even and odd terms:
$$ s(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n+1)} z^{2n} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+3/2)} z^{2n+1}. $$
The first sum is recognisable as
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \Gamma(1/2) \binom{-1/2}{n} z^{2n} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}. $$
The second one is more annoying: I haven't got a nice way of doing it (yet...), apart from hurling it into the hypergeometric world:
$$ {}_2F_1(a,b;c;z) = \frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(k+a)\Gamma(k+b)}{\Gamma(k+c)} \frac{z^k}{k!}, $$
so the second term is obviously
$$ \frac{1}{\Gamma(3/2)} z {}_2F_1(1,1;\tfrac{1}{2};z^2) = \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{\arcsin{z}}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}, $$
using the ancient art of "looking it up in tables". Hence we have to find
$$ \lim_{z \uparrow 1} \frac{\pi-2\arcsin{z}}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}. $$

This is straightforward after we remember that $\pi/2-\arcsin{z}=\arccos{z}$. For $\theta$ close to $0$,
$$ \cos{\theta} \sim 1 - \frac{\theta^2}{2} $$
and rearranging gives
$$ \arccos{z} \sim \sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-z}, $$
for $z$ close to $1$, which cancels with the denominator's contribution and gives your answer.

Comment: Many thanks, that looks nice! (+1)

Comment: Very nice solution, indeed !

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is the kind of answer of interest to you; so, forgive me if I am off topic.

Playing a little with the properties of the gamma function, what you can show is that $$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{k}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{k}{2}+1\right)}=2 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi
   }}-\frac{\Gamma \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor +2\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor +\frac{3}{2}\right)}+\frac{\Gamma
   \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor +\frac{3}{2}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor +1\right)}\right)$$

Comment: Many thanks. This is nice, I will try to understand the details by myself. (+1)